# d3js charts, Use json strings instead of json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This is my very first to d3js.I have use this d3js [Line Chart Sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).But after feeding the data it doesn't draw the chart but i can see the data has been loaded by using the firebug.But the data doesn't print in the graph at all. Could n't figure out the problem.Any help will be really appreciated.

This is My code,

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp);
    })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.memberAverageLoadAverage); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var json1=[
{
    "clusterId": "",
    "timeStamp": 1437063744524,
    "memberAverageLoadAverage": 20,
    "memberId": ""
},
{
    "clusterId": "",
    "timeStamp": 1437069850060,
    "memberAverageLoadAverage": 20,
    "memberId": ""
},
{
    "clusterId": "",
    "timeStamp": 1437069910059,
    "memberAverageLoadAverage": 20,
    "memberId": ""
},
{
    "clusterId": "",
    "timeStamp": 1437069970060,
    "memberAverageLoadAverage": 20,
    "memberId": ""
},
{
    "clusterId": "",
    "timeStamp": 1437070030056,
    "memberAverageLoadAverage": 20,
    "memberId": ""
}
```

];

```
root = json1;

  x.domain(d3.extent(root, function(d) { return d.timeStamp; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(root, function(d) { return   d.memberAverageLoadAverage; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("memberAverageLoadAverage");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(root)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: You cannot `JSON.parse(json1);` as it is already a JS object, so you can just do `root = json1;` in your example. If you change your memeberAverageLoadAverage numbers from all being the same value then you should start seeing some lines.

Comment: sorry i tried it but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the `JSON.parse` for the JS object and changing the `memberAverageLoadAverage` to not all be the same value, I was able to display a graph. The reason I needed to change the `memberAverageLoadAverage` values is that the `extent` call was making the y axis go from 20 to 20 so the line was at the bottom of the screen and collided with the x axis line. I would suggest setting the `y.domain` to `[0, d3.max(...)]` instead of using `d3.extent`.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp);
    })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.memberAverageLoadAverage); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var json1=[{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437063744524,"memberAverageLoadAverage":11,"memberId":""},{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069850060,"memberAverageLoadAverage":5,"memberId":""},{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069910059,"memberAverageLoadAverage":6,"memberId":""},{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437069970060,"memberAverageLoadAverage":15,"memberId":""},{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437070030056,"memberAverageLoadAverage":20,"memberId":""}];

var data = json1;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timeStamp; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.memberAverageLoadAverage; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much Brant Olsen.It works. :) thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a comment, but I suggest a couple of things. 1. I suggest using externally loaded JSON data if you have a server you can use to get the http request. If not, then you can use local data, but either way you have to have a data.foreach function in which you create all of your values, similar to the oneseen below.

```
data.foreach(function(d) {
    d.timeStamp = d.timeStamp;
    d.memberAverageLoadAverage = +d.memberAverageLoadAverage;
});
```

I also strongly suggest you reformat your JSON because your keys are not done phenomenally well, so I suggest you take a look [here](https://jsonblob.com/55a6c50fe4b051e806c97d61) and reformat the data. Let me know how you do and what else I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can parse this. It is an array. Anyways, even if you can,  I don't think there is a need to parse it.

```
  `var json1=`[{"clusterId":"","timeStamp":1437063744524,"memberAverageLoadAverage":20,"memberId":""},
```